# Setting the Overall column to report column percentage in gtsummary

Tags: gtsummary

I would like to have the Overall have column percentage whereas the other columns report row percentages. How would one go about that. Thanks in advance.

```
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)


trial %>%
  select(age, grade, response, trt) %>%
  tbl_summary(by=trt, percent = "row",
              type = response ~ "categorical",
              missing = "no") %>%
  add_overall()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results from `add_overall()` will always be consistent with the call in `tbl_summary()`. To get what you're after, build two tables and merge them. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)

tbl_row_percent <- 
  trial %>%
  select(age, grade, response, trt) %>%
  tbl_summary(by=trt, percent = "row",
              type = response ~ "categorical",
              missing = "no") 

tbl_col_percent <- 
  trial %>%
  select(age, grade, response) %>%
  tbl_summary(type = response ~ "categorical",
              missing = "no") %>%
  modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**Overall**, N = {N}")

tbl_final <-
  tbl_merge(list(tbl_col_percent, tbl_row_percent)) %>%
  modify_spanning_header(everything() ~ NA)
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-08-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>